# Locus of reflection:Special case

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, reflection, locus

In a triangle ABC, right angled at C, points A and B are fixed. C moves on a circle with AB as diameter.Suppose I is the incentre and the incircle touches the hypotenuse at F. What is the locus of the reflection of F across  CI?

I proceeded with coordinates, taking  $A(-1,0),B(1,0)$and $C(cos2\theta,sin2\theta)$.I obtained a parametric form of locus.But the coordinates of the reflection are quite complicated to determine a geometric form straightaway. 
Here is an image with the coordinates of the reflection.

How do I remove the parameter?Is there any other euclidean geometry approach?

[image]

Comment: There is no "locus" if nothing is moving. When you draw all points, you have to move some point(s) according to some critera and then observe the locus of point $F'$. You need to clarify.

Comment: @Oldboy Realy sorry, yes I missed a detail. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: You got a parametric equation of the locus, what are you asking exactly?

Comment: @Aretino I imply the geometry of the locus.

Comment: The locus in [geogebra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDFFH.png).

Comment: Judging from the shape of the locus (see above comment) this is not some simple nice curve, if that was the object of your question.

Comment: @Jan-Magnus Økland @Aretino(Urgent) Can you please calculate the area under the curve?I tried with Geogebra but I dont know where I'm going wrong,here's the link-

https://www.geogebra.org/m/ckvzzsqj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterization you give seems to not plot right so I tried to find another one. I start as you did

$C$: $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$

[image: incenter locus]

For the incenter plug the side lengths $a=2\sin(t/2) ,b= 2\cos(t/2),c= 2$ and $x(A)=-1,x(B)=1,x(C)=\cos(t),y(A)=0,y(B)=0,y(C)=\sin(t)$ in the formula $(\frac{ax(A)+bx(B)+cx(C)}{a+b+c},\frac{ay(A)+by(B)+cy(C)}{a+b+c}).$

$I$: $(\frac{(2\sin(t/2)\cdot (-1)+2\cos(t/2)\cdot 1+2\cos(t)}{2\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)+2},\frac{2\sin(t)}{2\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)+2})$

$CI$: $y-\sin(t)=m\cdot (x-\cos(t))$

$m=\frac{\sin(t)-\frac{2\sin(t)}{2\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)+2}}{\cos(t)-\frac{(2\sin(t/2)\cdot (-1)+2\cos(t/2)\cdot 1+2\cos(t)}{2\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)+2}}$

For $F,$ use that the incircle has equation $(x-\frac{(2\sin(t/2)\cdot (-1)+2\cos(t/2)\cdot 1+2\cos(t))}{(2\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)+2)})^2+(y-\frac{(2\sin(t))}{(2\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)+2)})^2=(\cos(t/2)+\sin(t/2)-1)^2$ and intersect with $y=0.$

$F$ $(\frac{\cos(t)-\sin(t/2)+\cos(t/2)}{\sin(t/2)+\cos(t/2)+1},0)$

We're interested in the reflection $F'$ of $F$ in the line $CI$ for $t\in[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ in the first quadrant (replacing $t=2\frac{t}{2}$ by double angle formulas): $${\tiny x(t)=-\frac{(((2\cos(t/2)\sin(t/2)+1)((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)-4\cos(t/2)^2+2)(2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2))^2
 +((1-2\cos(t/2)^2)\sin(t/2)+2\cos(t/2)^3-\cos(t/2)-1)((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)+\sin(t/2)
 +2\cos(t/2)^2-\cos(t/2)-1)
 }{((2\sin(t/2)^3+(2\cos(t/2)+2)\sin(t/2)^2-\sin(t/2)-\cos(t/2)-1)((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)
  +\sin(t/2)+\cos(t/2)+1)}}$$
 $$ {\tiny y(t)=-\frac{((((2\cos(t/2)^2+1)\sin(t/2)-2\cos(t/2)^3+3\cos(t/2))((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)
 +(3-6\cos(t/2)^2)\sin(t/2)-6\cos(t/2)^3+3\cos(t/2))
 (2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2))^3
 +(((4\cos(t/2)^2-4)\sin(t/2)-4\cos(t/2)^3)((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)
  +(4\cos(t/2)^2-4)\sin(t/2)+4\cos(t/2)^3)
  (2\sin(t/2)\cos(t/2)))
 }{(((4\cos(t/2)+2)\sin(t/2)^3+(2\cos(t/2)+2)\sin(t/2)^2
                             +((-2\cos(t/2))-1)\sin(t/2)-\cos(t/2)-1)
  ((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)^2
  +(4\sin(t/2)^4+2\sin(t/2)^3+((-2\cos(t/2))-4)\sin(t/2)^2+2\cos(t/2)\sin(t/2)
                +2\cos(t/2)+2)
   ((\cos(t/2))^2-(\sin(t/2))^2)+2\sin(t/2)^2+\sin(t/2)-\cos(t/2)-1)}}$$

To answer the question in the comments, the area under the curve in the first quadrant is 
$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}yx'dt$ so that the area of the shape is $4I$ (in maxima CAS):

```
/* trigsimp(y*diff(x,t)) */
((24*cos(t/2)+16)*sin(t/2)^8+((-32*cos(t/2))-44)*sin(t/2)^7+(12-20*cos(t/2))*sin(t/2)^6+(52*cos(t/2)+50)*sin(t/2)^5+((-28*cos(t/2))-38)*sin(t/2)^4+((-2*cos(t/2))-2)*sin(t/2)^3+(8*cos(t/2)+8)*sin(t/2)^2+((-2*cos(t/2))-2)*sin(t/2))/(2*sin(t/2)^3-sin(t/2)^2+((-3*cos(t/2))-3)*sin(t/2)+2*cos(t/2)+2)
quad_qag(%,t,0,%pi/2,3,'epsrel=5d-8);
```

$\approx-0.07079632679489668$

making the area inside the whole locus $\approx 0.283184$.

Comment: `R=QQ[c,s,x,y]`
`I=ideal((2*s^5+(2*c+2)*s^4+((-2*c^2)-1)*s^3+((-2*c^3)-2*c^2-c-1)*s^2+(c^2-1)*s+c^3+c^2-c-1)*x+(8*c^3*s^5+4*c^2*s^4+((-8*c^5)-2*c^2+1)*s^3+(12*c^4+2*c^3-8*c^2-c-1)*s^2+(2*c^4-c^2-1)*s-2*c^5+c^3-c^2+c+1), (((4*c+2)*s^7+(2*c-2)*s^6+((-8*c^3)-4*c^2-2*c-3)*s^5+((-4*c^3)+c+3)*s^4+(4*c^5+2*c^4+4*c^3+4*c^2-2*c)*s^3+(2*c^5+2*c^4-2*c^2-2*c)*s^2+((-2*c^5)-c^4+2*c^3+1)*s-c^5-c^4+2*c^3+2*c^2-c-1))*y-(((16*c^5+8*c^3)*s^6+(24*c^4-16*c^6)*s^5+((-16*c^7)+40*c^5-16*c^3-8*c)*s^4+(16*c^8+24*c^6-32*c^4)*s^3+(8*c-8*c^5)*s^2+(8*c^6-8*c^4)*s)),c^2+s^2-1)`
`gens gb I`
`toString factor oo_0_0`

Comment: $(x)(x-1)(x+1)(x^6+3x^4y^2+6x^4y-x^4+3x^2y^4+12x^2y^3+10x^2y^2-2x^2y+y^6+6y^5+11y^4+6y^3+y^2)(s)^3(s-1)(s+1)^2$

Comment: Heck lot of effort man, I appreciate that!

Comment: But I still get a feeling that it has a beautiful euclidean geometry approach (•_•),maybe uses Inversion or something